# Recurrent neural network using different time steps with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I build RNN using keras but when I want to change time steps to different size I get an error and I can't get it done
here is my example for dummy data

```
from numpy import array
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras import optimizers


X=array(
    [
        [#first sample
            [0,2],[1,2],[2,2]    # three time steps and 2 features
        ]
        ,
        [# sample 2
            [0,2],[1,2],[2,2]    # three time steps and 2 features
        ]
        ,
        [# sample 3
            [7,2], [9,2], [4,2]  # three time steps and 2 features
        ]
        ,
        [# sample 4
            [2,2], [5,2], [4,2],[7,9]  # four steps and 2 features
        ]
    ]
)


Y=np.array([1,2,3,4])


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(8, input_shape=(None, 2),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(58, activation='softmax'))
optimize=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimize,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=1,epochs=50,shuffle=True,verbose=2)
```

as you can see from the code I have 4 sequence and 2 features in each sequence.
in the last sequence I have 4 time steps instead of 3 and here is the problem if I change it to 3 time steps the code works correctly, 
but I want it to work on different time steps how can I achieve that without use padding or masking.

I did read different topics describe different solutions but I can't get it work in the above example

when I try to run above code I got error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `X` is not a valid array. A numpy array must be rectangular and not jagged. Keras can only take in valid numpy arrays as inputs. You have two choices:

1. Feed the samples into your model 1 sample at a time. I.e. use a batch_size of 1, use `fit_on_batch` or `fit_generator` rather than just `fit`. Note that this will remove all vectorization related speed-optimizations and will slow your training down to a crawl if you have a lot of data.
2. Pad your training set so that they all are of the same time dimension. 0-padding shouldn't really affect the performance of your model. This is the recommended method.

See [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/85) thread for more details.

Comment: thanks for the great answer.
should it give better results if I use fit_on_batch instead of padding the training set? even if it will take much time ? or not ?

Comment: @osama generally padding the training set is the preferred method, it shouldn't affect your model accuracy that much.

Comment: Along with zero padding, use `Masking` layer so that zeros are truly ignored https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking.